# Convert string to list and nest in data.table

Tags: r, regex, data.table, nested-lists

I am trying to coerce an ugly character string imported from python into a list where it can occupy a cell in a data.table.

To make clearer, I currently have a .tsv that has some rows that look like this:

```
1    2    [1, 2, 3, 4]    4
```

When I import this via `fread`, I end up with a string for the third element (i.e. `dt[1,3] = "[1, 2, 3, 4]"`).

My current solution is to convert these items to a list with regex. For example:

```
dt[, newList := .(list(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(gsub("\\[|\\]","", 3),",")))))]
```

But I find this extremely ugly and unsatisfying.

Is there a more elegant way of doing this? Ideally I would also replace the original variable, which isn't currently possible by reference due to the different column classes.

Alternatively, is there a better way I can export a .csv or .tsv with nested lists from python that would allow a better read into R?

It seems like the `sep2` data.table argument would be particularly useful here, but it has yet to be implemented.

Any solutions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sorry, what's the question here?  To convert the list in a column ?

Comment: export nested lists as JSON.

Comment: is this `r` or `python`?

Comment: This is `r`, but there might also be a `python` export solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I think it's bound to be somewhat ugly (note we must use `as.list` to signify to `:=` that a column type change is occurring):

```
DT = data.table(a = 1, b = 2, c = '[1, 2, 3, 4]', d = 4)
DT[ , c := as.list(lapply(
  strsplit(gsub('[][]', '', c), ',', fixed = TRUE),
  as.integer))]
```

Unfortunately your example is *too* minimal, as it's not clear what you'd like to do for input table with more than one row.

Sooner or later, [`fread` will support a `sep2`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1162) argument that will handle this automatically...

Comment: would `tstrsplit` be more appropriate?

Comment: @SymbolixAU perhaps; depends on OP's use case. In their question they say "a list [occupying] a cell" so I assumed they wanted a list column

Comment: Yes, @SymbolixAU, list column is what I'm after. 

This is already much better! For more than one row I am just iterating through each row (i.e. `DT[ , c := asAbove(c), by = row]`). Using your solution as a function and specifying which columns are of this type seems to be a reasonable way to apply this to multiple rows/columns.

Comment: @BowenJFung this should work to convert an entire column at once, if i'm not mistaken